# MS Graph API - Group & membership info

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, powershell-7.3

I'm trying to pull out a listing of all groups in our Azure Active Directory org along with all the associated members (be them users, groups, contacts, etc).

Since I was unable to locate a method to do this through the various Microsoft portals with a simple export button I began the process of obtaining access to the Microsoft Graph API/SDK via Powershell.

I'm by no means a PowerShell expert as it's not one of my go-to scripts; however, from what I can tell the ability to pull group info in this fashion is fairly limited.

The following is what I've been able to accomplish thus far:

- Pull in a list of the groups using `Get-MgGroup -All`
- Use `Get-MgGroupMembers` to pull back a list of Directory Objects.

This is where I get stuck.  From what I've read it looks like a Directory Object by default only returns the ID and the Deleted Date.  I'd like to get a display Name for these objects; I can obviously do this by running the appropriate 'Get' cmdlet for the type of directory object (i.e. `Get-MgUser`);  From what I can tell the type of directory object can't be gleaned via PowerShell with out 'trial-and-error'... This seems highly inefficient to simply get a displayName.

Is there a more effective way to determine either the displayName of a Directory Object via a PowerShell cmdlet or at the very least a type so I can write a case statement to run the right cmdlet on the first try?

For the record this is going to be incorporated in to a Powershell Script, the current iteration of which looks like this and sorta works okay... assuming the Id passed in `$member.Id` belongs to a User type directory object.

```
Connect-MgGraph
$groups=Get-mgGroup -All
ForEach ($group in $groups){
    $members = @{}
    $members = Get-MgGroupMember -GroupId $group.Id -All
    ForEach ($member in $members){
        $user = Get-MgUser $member.Id
        Write-Output $object.ODataType
        Write-output $group.DisplayName "," $member.Id "," $user.UserType"," $user.DisplayName "," $user.UserPrincipalName "," $user.Mail >> C:scripts\Azure_Groups.txt
    }
}
```

Would appreciate any direction/assistance on this.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Get-MgGroupMember returns objects that can be users, devices, other groups, or service principals. You should at least check if you have a **user** object before calling on Get-MgUser. Isn't there an `.ObjectType` property that would show this?

Comment: @Theo - that was my assumption too, but from what I can tell it looks like it's in the ODATA which I can't find a way to expand/query from PowerShell

`$newGroup = Get-MgGroup -Filter "displayName eq '<groupName>'"`
`Write-Output $newGroup.ObjectType` returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why its not returning all the details on the PowerShell query:

[image]

This is working fine in MS Graph Explorer with the results showing all the details of the members:

[image]

For more details:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-1-get-the-direct-membership-in-a-group